# postgresql delete with select condition

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to delete data by using subquery after condition, but my trick fail when my sql script is executed 
this is my script:

```
--trying to insert subquery after "=" operator

delete from wni_layanan where id = SELECT (currval('wni_layanan_id_seq'));
```

this is error message who apears in my sqleditor after script executed

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "SELECT"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 36
```

how to delete with select condition in postgresql ?
please give me solution to solve my problem. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the whole sub-select in parentheses. You also should not wrap a "standalone" function call (or expression) like `currval('..')` in parentheses.

```
delete from wni_layanan 
where id = (SELECT currval('wni_layanan_id_seq') );
```

The above will **only** work correctly if the subselect returns **exactly** one row (and one column). When using `currval()` this is guaranteed. If your sub-query returns several rows you need to use `IN (..)`

```
delete from wni_layanan 
where id IN (SELECT ... );
```

But for your example you don't need the sub-select at all:

```
delete from wni_layanan 
where id = currval('wni_layanan_id_seq');
```

Comment: subquery is necesary tobe placing inside "( )" symbol,it work's thank U
delete from wni_layanan where id IN ( SELECT (currval('wni_layanan_id_seq')));
thank you :D

Comment: @Alimin: it's totally unnecessary (and useless) to wrap the `currval()` into _another_ level or parentheses like you do.

Comment: I use curval() to deleting when data is exist and try to make something without long and complicated php script , I mean another action made just in single sqlscript .